# Crawling a Google login protected web page

Tags: web-crawler

I want to crawl a website that is protected by Google login. E.g., threads in a private group on https://groups.google.com that are only visible after I login with my Google account. How can I automate the code so it authenticates using my account, and crawl the HTML from the site? Also, how does it detect a login expiration, and re-login?

Comment: Show us what you tried so far, some code, examples, something. Tell us where you're stuck or what specific problem you have. Recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Examples I found so far are: [Login web form](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/), and [Google API](http://highaltitudedev.blogspot.com/2013/10/google-oauth2-with-jettyservlets.html). But the first link doesn't have much automation and seems hacky, while the second link works with Google API that doesn't seem to be related to web crawling with automated login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using phantomJs for crawling.